# Edit DataGridView cells in Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

When I use Linq-to-Entities to bind the data in my database to a DataGridView in a C# application I am making the DataGridView become Read-Only and can't be edited.

Is it possible to edit the data in the DataGridView and the changes saved in the database ?

This is the code where I bind the data to the DGV after applying some filtering to the first query:

```
private void ViewResults(IQueryable<Hero> viewResult)
{
     dgdResult.DataSource = (from r in viewResult
                             select new
                             {
                                 Name   = r.Name,
                                 Rarity = r.Rarity,
                                 Speed  = r.Speed,
                                 Attack = r.Attack,
                                 Target = r.Target
                              }).ToList(); 
 }
```

Comment: Yes. I've read that it has something to do with anonymous types but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's interesting, I didn't realize it did that with anonymous types. Pretty easy to reproduce though.

The easiest thing is probably to create a private class with just the fields you need, inside the Form since you won't be using it anywhere else.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ...
    ...

    private void ViewResults(IQueryable<Hero> viewResult)
    {
        dgdResult.DataSource = (from r in viewResult
                                select new LittleHero
                                           {
                                               Name = r.Name,
                                               Rarity = r.Rarity,
                                               Speed = r.Speed,
                                               Attack = r.Attack,
                                               Target = r.Target
                                           }).ToList();
    }

    private class LittleHero
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Rarity { get; set; }
        public string Speed { get; set; }
        public string Attack { get; set; }
        public string Target { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As for saving it, that's kinda broad and depends on what technologies you're using.

You can easily get the collection back from the DataGridView by casting the DataSource though.

```
var heroes = (List<LittleHero>)dgdResult.DataSource;
```

Comment: That confirms it, anonymous types will make the GridView uneditable. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to [C# Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types):

> Anonymous types provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of **read-only** properties into a single object without having to explicitly define a type first.