# Can't edit my datagridview after binding to XML file via linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, datagridview

Links to 2 similar examples on here which I can't really link to my exact case.
[Similalr example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311683/unable-to-edit-datagridview-populated-with-results-of-linq-query)

[Similar Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397280/edit-datagridview-cells-in-linq-to-entities)

Here is the code that populates my datagridview...

```
XElement xdoc = XElement.Load(@"C:\xmltest\test.xml");

            var lines = from item in xdoc.Descendants("line")
                        let fields = item.Elements("field")
                        select new
                        {
                            Name = (string)fields
                                .FirstOrDefault(n => (string)n.Attribute("name") == "Name"),
                            Description = (string)fields
                                .FirstOrDefault(n => (string)n.Attribute("name") == "Description"),
                            ExtraDetails = (string)fields
                                .FirstOrDefault(n => (string)n.Attribute("name") == "ExtraDetails"),

                        };


            dataGridView1.DataSource = lines.ToArray();
```

This works fine but I can't edit the datagridview after the 'import'.  I have defiantly set the datagridview settings to allow editing etc. The problem seems to be related to the databind in some way.

Comment: check if datagridview1.readonly=true; This might be causing problem

Comment: it's not that as i mentioned I checked all the data grid view settings. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are projecting the result to [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). The very first line in the documentation link states

> Anonymous types provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of **read-only** properties into a single object without having to explicitly define a type first.

Hope you noticed the **read-only** word.

If you want to get editable data, then create your own class with read/write properties and project the query result into it.