# Edit DataGrid when select new is used in LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

the problem is, when i use "Select New" statemet i'm no longer allowed to edit information in DataGrid and SubmitChanges to sql server.

```
dataGrid2.ItemsSource = from a in dc.Provider from c in dc.ProviderItems 
                        where a.Name == comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() 
                        from b in dc.Category 
                        where b.CategoryID == c.CategoryID 
                        where c.ProviderID == a.ProviderID 
                        select new { 
                                     Name = c.Name, 
                                     Price = c.ProviderPrice, 
                                     Category = b.Name 
                                   };
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648856/cant-edit-my-datagridview-after-binding-to-xml-file-via-linq/33649231#33649231

Comment: I checked it already. When I use, for example, 'select a;', instead of 'select new...', everything works perfectly. I read that it's because select new creates some kind of virtual table, which is not related to the original one, that's why it's not allowed to edit.

Comment: Read it again. The section (and the link) about **anonymous type**, because this is what `new { ... }` is producing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating a new class that has these 3 properties (Name, Price, Category) and instead of doing select new {} do something like:

```
select new MyNewClass
{ 
    Name = c.Name,
    Price = c.ProviderPrice, 
    Category = b.Name
};
```

Comment: Now i can edit DataGrid, but I can't submit changes.

Comment: Yes I know but I think you should use this approach my creating your UI Models and then create custom repositories to push changes down to your database.

Comment: @Unholyan tell me if you need more help with that I'll show you own to deal with it.